# In Craft Commerce, is it possible to show a more meaningful error when the customer tries to add more of a product than is in stock to the cart

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce3

Currently, if a customer attempts to add a greater quantity of a product to the cart than is in stock, an "Unable to update cart" flash message in shown.  e.g. there are 3 in stock and the customer tries to add 4 to their cart.

Is there any way to change what that error says? As obviously a customer isn't going to know what that means.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify the error message, the way to do is not to use the craft.app.session.getFlash('error') value but use the `cart.errors` instead. Each of the errors has a unique key for specific error then you can add a condition on what message to display. It would something this.

```
{% if cart.errors|length %}
            <ul>
            {% for attribute, errors in cart.errors %}
               {% if attribute == "lineItems.0.qty" %}
                    {% for key, error in errors %}
                        <li>Product is not available</li>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% else %}
                    {% for key, error in errors %}
                        <li>{{ attribute }}: {{ error }}</li>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
{% endif %}
```

You could also modify the Unable to cart message by adding this to the update cart form
E.g.

```
{{ hiddenInput('failMessage', 'Error adding cart.'|hash) }}
```